# JupyterLab Python Notebook - Pandas - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

this is my code.

```
new_cases = pd.DataFrame()
for column in range(1, 573):
  new_cases[column] = cases.iloc[:,column] - cases.iloc[:,column - 1]

new_deaths = pd.DataFrame()
for column in range(1, 573):
  new_deaths[column] = deaths.iloc[:,column] - deaths.iloc[:,column - 1]

display(new_cases.head())
display(new_deaths.head())
```

Every time to I attempt to run I get this message:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Sorry if this is a really dumb question. I'm attempting to self teach myself data analysis with Pandas.

Appreciate any answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code you are running is subtracting 2 adjacent columns and store the results in your new dataframe. It errors because there are 2 columns which don't have the same datatype: it is trying to do a substraction with a string and an int.

Make sure the datatype of your columns are consistent or cast your values if you are certain all columns are numbers.